# Why decrement %rsp when everything can be done via registers?

Tags: c, assembly, gcc, x86-64, instruction-set

Below is my code:

**C code**

```
// this function might look weird, just for demo purpose
void func4(int x, int y, int z) {
    int t = z - y;
    int k = t >> 31;
    t = (t + k) >> 1;
    k = t + y;
    if(k <= x) {
        t = 0;
        if(k >= 1) {
            return;
        }else {
            y = k + 1;
            func4(x, y, z);
        }
    }else {
        z = k - 1;
        func4(x, y, z);
    }
}
```

**asssembly code:**

```
// only show relevant code
func4:
   subq $8, %rsp     //  decrement %rsp by 8, but why?
   movl %edx, %eax
   subl %esi, %eax
   ...               //  all operations on registers
   addq $8, %rsp
   ret
```

So since every operation can be done via registers, nothing is pushed to the stack, no pointer involved, so why the `%rsp` is decremented by 8 in the first place? Is it for alignment/offset?

Answer (score 5):

`func4` makes an outgoing function call (to itself no less) and thus must honor the ABI for function calls, that requires `%rsp` to be aligned mod 16 at the time of call (and thus misaligned by 8 on entry due to the return address being pushed).

Comment: Maybe it's optimized to a tail jmp that skips the prologue?

Comment: No, it's not to optimize anything. It's just to satisfy the ABI. The ABI exists for callee to be free to use SSE without having to readjust the stack in a variable way that's more expensive to restore.

Comment: Yeah, but the callee and caller are the same in this case, as such an optimisation like aforementioned may be applied, thus invalidating your argument. It could also just be a code generation artifact.

Comment: @super: Compilers generally don't make that type of optimization, at least not in code that's compiled to be usable in shared libraries, due to their support for interposition. For example it's possible that `func4` is actually defined first in another library or the main program, but this version still gets called via an alias to it or via `dlsym`. There's some disagreement over the degree to which this kind of thing should be supported, but generally the compiler aims to match ABI wherever it creates a conceivably-really-external call boundary.